# MFCC example problem: [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000271380> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46

Tags: c++, macos, audio, openframeworks, mfcc

I am using MFCC to Wekinator example by Rebecca Fiebrink, 2016, and I found that it is quite outdated so I am trying to fix it. I have fixed most of the problems but only have one error that’s not working

MFCCs_13InputsDebug[40247:700556] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000271380> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46

The codes are over here:

```
    #ifndef _OF_APP
#define _OF_APP


#include "ofMain.h"
#include "ofxMaxim.h"

#include "maxiMFCC.h"
#include "ofxOsc.h"

#define HOST "localhost"
#define PORT 6448

class ofApp : public ofBaseApp{
    
public:
    ~ofApp();/* deconsructor is very useful */
    void setup();
    void update();
    void draw();
    
    void keyPressed  (int key);
    void keyReleased(int key);
    void mouseMoved(int x, int y );
    void mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button);
    void mousePressed(int x, int y, int button);
    void mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button);
    void windowResized(int w, int h);
    
    void audioRequested     (float * input, int bufferSize, int nChannels); /* output method */
    void audioReceived  (float * input, int bufferSize, int nChannels); /* input method */
    
    float   * lAudioOut; /* outputs */
    float   * rAudioOut;
    
    float * lAudioIn; /* inputs */
    float * rAudioIn;
    
    int     initialBufferSize; /* buffer size */
    int     sampleRate;
    
    
    /* stick your maximilian stuff below */
    double wave;
    ofxMaxiFFTOctaveAnalyzer oct;
    int nAverages = 12;
    
    ofxMaxiIFFT ifft;
    ofxMaxiFFT mfft;
    int fftSize = 1024;
    int bins, dataSize;
    
    maxiMFCC mfcc;
    double *mfccs;
    
    ofxOscSender sender;
    
    ofTrueTypeFont myfont;
};

#endif
```

```
    /* MFCC to Wekinator example by Rebecca Fiebrink, 2016
 
 Adapted from Maximilian example code
 
 */


#include "ofApp.h"
#include "maximilian.h"/* include the lib */
#include "time.h"

//-------------------------------------------------------------
ofApp::~ofApp() {
    
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::setup(){
    
    sender.setup(HOST, PORT);
    
    //Load font
    myfont.loadFont("Alibaba-PuHuiTi-Light.ttf", 10);
    
    /* some standard setup stuff*/
    ofEnableAlphaBlending();
    ofSetupScreen();
    ofBackground(0, 0, 0);
    ofSetFrameRate(60);
    
    /* This is stuff you always need when you use Maximilian. Don't change it.*/
    sampleRate          = 44100; /* Sampling Rate */
    initialBufferSize   = 512;  /* Buffer Size. you have to fill this buffer with sound*/
    lAudioOut           = new float[initialBufferSize];/* outputs */
    rAudioOut           = new float[initialBufferSize];
    lAudioIn            = new float[initialBufferSize];/* inputs */
    rAudioIn            = new float[initialBufferSize];
    
    
    /* This is a nice safe piece of code */
    memset(lAudioOut, 0, initialBufferSize * sizeof(float));
    memset(rAudioOut, 0, initialBufferSize * sizeof(float));
    memset(lAudioIn, 0, initialBufferSize * sizeof(float));
    memset(rAudioIn, 0, initialBufferSize * sizeof(float));
    
    /* Now you can put anything you would normally put in maximilian's 'setup' method in here. */
    
    mfft.setup(fftSize, 512, 256); //just a forward FFT
    oct.setup(sampleRate, fftSize/2, nAverages);
    mfccs = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * 13);
    
    //512 bins, 42 filters, 13 coeffs, min/max freq 20/20000
    mfcc.setup(512, 42, 13, 20, 20000, sampleRate);
    
    ofxMaxiSettings::setup(sampleRate, 2, initialBufferSize);
    ofSoundStreamSetup(2,1, this, sampleRate, initialBufferSize, 4);/* Call this last ! */
    
    
    
    ofSetVerticalSync(true);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::update(){
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::draw(){
    
    ofSetColor(255, 255, 255,255);
    
    ofSetColor(0, 255, 0, 255);
    myfont.drawString("Sending 13 inputs to port 6448\nUsing message /wek/inputs", 8, 10);
    
    //Draw MFCC values:
    ofSetColor(0, 255, 0,255);
    float xinc = 190.0 / 13;
    for(int i=0; i < 13; i++) {
        float height = mfccs[i] * 200.0;
        ofDrawRectangle(10 + (i*xinc),200 - height,10, height);
    }
    
    //Send OSC:
    ofxOscMessage m;
    m.setAddress("/wek/inputs");
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        m.addFloatArg(mfccs[i]);
    }
    sender.sendMessage(m);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::audioRequested  (float * output, int bufferSize, int nChannels){
    //  static double tm;
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++){
        wave = lAudioIn[i];
        
        //Calculate the mfccs
        if (mfft.process(wave)) { //is the window buffer full?
            mfft.magsToDB();
            oct.calculate(mfft.magnitudesDB);
            mfcc.mfcc(mfft.magnitudes, mfccs);
        }
        
        memset(lAudioOut, 0, initialBufferSize * sizeof(float));
        memset(rAudioOut, 0, initialBufferSize * sizeof(float));
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::audioReceived   (float * input, int bufferSize, int nChannels){
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++){
        
        /* grab the data out of the arrays*/
        lAudioIn[i] = input[i*2];
        rAudioIn[i] = input[i*2+1];
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::keyPressed(int key){
    
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::keyReleased(int key){
    
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::mouseMoved(int x, int y ){
    
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button){
    
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::mousePressed(int x, int y, int button){
    
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button){
    
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::windowResized(int w, int h){
    
}
```

My Deployment Target is macOS 10.9, and I am using Xcode12.4. It did ask me permission to use the microphone before it runs, which is a good thing, but there are no bars showing up that signify the sounds. Is there anyone who can help me?